# ClockView resize and orientation of activity

Tags: android, textview

I am making an app that would show a digital clock in fullscreen mode.
API 19 and up.

I used `ClockView` for this but the size of text(time) is not (re)fitting itself to the whole screen. I would like it to adjust itself as per the screen size. But it isn't.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    float fontscale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;

    float textSize = (width/fontscale)/5;

    textclock.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,  textSize);
```

I know text should be in `sp` unit. But I am not sure how to exactly do that calculation. I tried some answers here on SO about PX to SP conversion but it is not working. It zooms in too much. 
How can I achieve text resize reliably. I have tried few 'solutions' on OS. I either don't understand them or they don't work.
I was also thinking may be I should use transparent text images of digits then will use them to display time. Background color can be changed for these images. I can create them for different device screen sizes. But I don't know how to get transparent TEXT. I tried online app but they create transparent backgrounds with colored text. I want see through TEXT(font)(may be cut-out transparent image that is of a digit?) that I use for `ImageView` and then have a background color for it? can Anyone has any comments about this approach?

Another issue related to this app is, I have set activity orientation as landscape in the `Manifest.xml` but it goes into portrait orientation and then into landscape. How do I make sure it starts in landscape mode without user noticing the transition?